# tkinter widget call back to identify details about the widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was reading http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf
and started playing around with "54.7. The extra arguments trick" located towards the end of the document.  If I understand it correctly, I can create widgets in a list, so that when the widget is clicked on, the callback should be able to display information stored in the instantiated class, I get the widget to display, but the callback is not displaying the info that I expected.  IE the attributes of the object created -  Hopefully someone can help.  thanks in advance

here is the code

```
from tkinter import *
class Component(object):
    def __init__(self, image=None, Number=None, Name=None):
        self.image=image
        self.Number=Number
        self.Name=Name

ComponentList = []     #array of componenents

def FeederCB(event):
    print(event.widget.Number, event.widget.Name)

root = Tk()

test=Frame(root, bg='white')
test.grid()

for x in range(0, 2):
    print(x)
    ComponentList.append(Component(None, str(x),"Poly 23"))
    Temp=Label(test, text=ComponentList[-1].Name)
    Temp.configure(bg='white', font='times 12')
    Temp.grid(row=0, column=x, sticky=S)
    ComponentList[-1].image = (Label(test, text='test'))
    ComponentList[-1].image.configure(bg='white')
    ComponentList[-1].image.bind("<Button-1>",FeederCB)
    ComponentList[-1].image.grid(row=1, column=x)
print('Lenght of Component List ', len(ComponentList))
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it

```
from tkinter import *
class Component(object):
    def __init__(self, image=None, Number=None, Name=None):
        self.image=image
        self.Number=Number
        self.Name=Name

ComponentList = []     #array of componenents
#ComponentList.append(Class object,class attibutes)
#example   ComponentList.append(Virgin("1", "materialtype", "Name", "Setpoint"))
#print(ComponentList[0].Name)


def __FeederCB(event, x):
    print(ComponentList[x].Number, ComponentList[x].Name)

root = Tk()

test=Frame(root, bg='white')
test.grid()

for x in range(0, 2):
    print(x)
    ComponentList.append(Component(None, str(x),"Poly 23"))
    Temp=Label(test, text=ComponentList[-1].Name)
    Temp.configure(bg='white', font='times 12')
    Temp.grid(row=0, column=x, sticky=S)
    ComponentList[-1].image = (Label(test, text='test'))
    ComponentList[-1].image.configure(bg='white')
    def FeederCB(event, x=x):
        return __FeederCB(event, x)
    ComponentList[-1].image.bind("<Button-1>",FeederCB)
    ComponentList[-1].image.grid(row=1, column=x)
print('Lenght of Component List ', len(ComponentList))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you describe for other what made your problem solve and how you fixed it?